Prove that for natural numbers a,b,c If $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ then for integer n>2, $a^n + b^n < c^n$
I know im supposed to use that if $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ then exists integers r,s,d that
$a = d(r^2 - s^2)$ and $b = 2drs$ and $c = d(r^2 + s^2)$ but placing these in the equation i just cant get the inequality right.

Hint:  rewrite as $\left( \frac ac\right)^2+\left(\frac bc\right)^2=1$

See the figure of the unit  balls in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space

$a,b,c$ are natural, hence $\frac{a}{c} > 0$ and $\frac{b}{c} > 0$. Put $u = \frac{a}{c} $ and $v = \frac{b}{c}$ (see lulu's comment). We have $u^2 + v^2 = 1$, $u > 0$ and $v>0$. Hence $u \in (0,1)$ and $v \in (0,1)$. So $u^n< u^2$ and $v^n < v^2$ and $u^n + v^n < u^2 + v^2 = 1$.
